# фрагмент не отображает recyclerview

Tags: java, android

добрый вечер, не могу понять почему во фрагменте не отображается recyclerview. если надо код скину

```
public class CategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesAdapter.CategoriesViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Category> categoryList;
    private onCategoriesPositionClick onCategoriesPositionClick;

    public CategoriesAdapter (ArrayList<Category>categoriesList, onCategoriesPositionClick onCategoriesPositionClick){
        this.categoryList = categoriesList;
        this.onCategoriesPositionClick = onCategoriesPositionClick;
    }

    @Override
    public CategoriesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_categories, null);
        return new  CategoriesViewHolder (view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CategoriesViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.category.setText(categoryList.get(position).getCategory());
        holder.image_ic.setImageResource(categoryList.get(position).getImage_ic());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryList.size();
    }


     class CategoriesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView category;
        ImageView image_ic;
        LinearLayout linearlayout;

        public CategoriesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            category = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Category);
            image_ic = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Image_ic);
            linearlayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Category_linearLayout);

            linearlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    onCategoriesPositionClick.OnCategoriesClick(getAdapterPosition());

                }
            });

        }
    }
}

public class FragmentCategories extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_Category = "param1";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private CategoriesAdapter categoriesAdapter;
ArrayList<Category>categoryList = new ArrayList<>();

private onCategoryPositionSelectedListener mListener;

public FragmentCategories() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentCategories.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters

public static FragmentCategories newInstance(ArrayList<Category> categoryList) {
    FragmentCategories fragmentCategories = new FragmentCategories();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(ARG_Category,categoryList);
    fragmentCategories.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentCategories;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    if (getArguments() != null)
        categoryList = (ArrayList<Category>) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_Category);
}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false);

         recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_categories);
         recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
         categoriesAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter(categoryList, new onCategoriesPositionClick() {
             @Override
             public void OnCategoriesClick(int position) {
                 mListener.onCategoryPositionClick(position);
             }

            });
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(categoriesAdapter);

            return view;
        }



@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof onCategoryPositionSelectedListener) {
        mListener = (onCategoryPositionSelectedListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
    public interface onCategoryPositionSelectedListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name

        void onCategoryPositionClick(int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: `если надо код скину` - уж пожалуйста

Comment: а что именно скинуть? адаптер, фрагмент

Comment: в идеале [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно инфлейтите разметку в `onCreateViewHolder` Надо так:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_categories, parent, false);
```

**Почему так?**

Сейчас вы передаете в качестве контейнера `null`. Поэтому ваша `View` не прикрепляется к нему. В `onCreateViewHolder` приходит контейнер, к нему и надо подключить вашу `View`

Comment: спасибо, точно не заметила, но все равно не работает(

Comment: @лена, попробуйте убрать `setHasFixedSize`

Comment: убрала,не помогло(

Comment: @лена, обновил ответ

Comment: @лена, хм.. Попробуйте в `newInstance` просто сохранять данные в переменную фпагмента `fragmentCategories.categoryList = categoryList`

Comment: я не знаю что ему не так, не хочет

Comment: @лена, добавьте в вопрос код, как вы показываете фрагмент

Comment: private void showFragmentCategories(){
     FragmentCategories fragmentCategories = FragmentCategories.newInstance(categoryList);
     getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_container, fragmentCategories)
                .commit();
    }

Comment: @лена, раз уж такое дело, то выводите в логи размер коллекции на всех этапах. `Log.d("app", "newInstance = " + categoryList.size()` разместите перед созданием фрагмента, в `newInstance`, `onCreate` и `onCreateView` и запустите приложение с открытой вкладкой логов (Logcat)

Comment: Напишите где выводит 0

Comment: Главное, в логи выводите с подписью откуда лог.

Comment: размещаю лог. в конце после;подчеркивает

Comment: @лена, ах да, там скобочку ещё одну закройте и поставьте точку с запятой

Comment: так в том то и проблема, в активити где я показываю фрагмент все хорошо, а в самом фрагменте ругается, и закрываю скобочку и точку с запятой ставила, не хочет

Comment: @лена, скиньте где вы пишите лог и как